# passing multiple collections to the same express route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
app.get('/dbpage', function(req, res){            
        Chapters.find({}, function(err, allChapters){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            res.render('dbpage', {chapters: allChapters});
        }
    });
});
```

The code above is a small portion of my project, and it's working fine. `Chapters` is the collection's name which is part of my `books` database. But I have another collection (from the same database) that I'm trying to pass through the same route `/dbpage`. How would add this other collection to the code above? So I can access the information stored in this other collection in the `/dbpage` route.

I've seen some other answers that are more or less suited for what I'm trying to do, but they all seen overkill for such a simple thing. Any suggestions? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't invoke the same route name.  If you use duplicate route definitions, the one "listed first" will take precedence.  The only time the same route definition is allowed is if you utilize a different HTTP verb... such as POST, PUT, PATCH, etc.

Thus, if you truly want to use the same route, you need to pass query params and then push conditional logic in the route, such as:

```
app.get('/dbpage', function(req, res){
        let {someQueryParam} = req.query;
        if(someQueryParam === 'someSpecialValue'){
          //... do something different...     
        } else {       
          Chapters.find({}, function(err, allChapters){
          if(err){
              console.log(err);
          }else{
              res.render('dbpage', {chapters: allChapters});
          }
        }
    });
});
```

And, you'd invoke it with some endpoint such as:

```
yourDomain.com:3000/dbPage?someQueryParam="someSpecialValue"
```

Honestly though I'd advise against introducing conditional logic when at all possible.  If possible, just set up another endpoint.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I'm still a little confused. I think accessing both collections might be really simple, but not the way it is in my question, it's just a matter changing the whole `app.get`. Is it possible to do something like `books.find({ChaptersA, ChaptersB}, function(err, allChaptersA, allChaptersB)...`? Since it's just one main parameter: "books"